# Reach docker container IP from outside of the Proxmox VM

Tags: docker, proxy, ip

Hy guys,

I face an ugly issue when trying do create my own gitlab server using docker (container IP 172.20.0.5).

I run a docker engine in a proxmox VM (VM ip is 192.168.0.37) and I try to reach from outside of the VM.

I've tried to read proxmox manual to find port mapping to redirect to the container IP when connecting to the VM IP but I didn't found how to reach my goal.

can somebody help me or at least give me a way to go through this ?

thanks everybody !

Comment: The container-private IP addresses are inaccessible in a variety of common scenarios, including this one.  I'd avoid looking them up at all.  You should be able to call the service using the VM's IP address and its published ports (`docker run -p` option, Compose `ports:`).

Comment: Thank you for your help, here is my docker compose file (the port part) :     ports:
     - '8088:80'
     - '4443:443'
so I should be able to acess the service using <VM_IP>:8088 ?

Comment: It's working, you're right, thanks a lor for your help David, the good port was the other (443 mapped to 4443)